# Is this number composite or prime: $2000^{2002} + 2000^{2000} + 1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Is this number composite or prime? $$2000^{2002} + 2000^{2000} + 1$$
I want to find an easy approach to this problem.

Comment: Where did this one come from?(So I know what methods are likely to be used)

Comment: Oh, teacher found this problem somewhere from an old math competition

Comment: I forget who said it first, but in response to this kind of question, "if it were prime, it would be unreasonable to expect a proof."

Comment: @DanielV I like this very much :).

Answer (score 6):

$$
2000^{2002}\equiv 1 (\text{mod 3}),\quad 2000^{2000}\equiv 1 (\text{mod 3})
$$
so your expression is divisible by $3$.

Comment: Beat me to it :)

Comment: @Committingtoachallenge I  thought the other way around when I saw "new comment ..." :)

Comment: Excellent! Better than teachers method. It was 1 page long. You are genious

Comment: Excuse me for a stupid question, just curious : why $2000^{2002} \equiv 1 \mod 3$?

Comment: @AndreiRykhalski: an easy way to see it is using $2000^2\equiv 1(\text{mod }3)$ and $a\equiv 1(\text{mod }b)$ implies $a^n\equiv 1(\text{mod }b)$.

Comment: @AndreiRykhalski E.g $2000^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 3$ and $1 \pmod 3 * 1 \pmod 3 = 1 \pmod 3$